# Python librairies not found and/or g++ compiler not found

Tags: python, cmake, g++, mingw-w64, anaconda3

I have different executables for python (by the way I am working on Windows), including C:\msys64\mingw64\bin and C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3.

When I add to my path variables the C:\msys64\mingw64\bin , Python fails to compile. When I remove it and put instead the C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3, the g++ compiler is not found.

The thing is : to execute my `cmake ..` command, I need python as well as the g++ compiler to be found.

I was thinking I could put the C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 in my path (so that it finds python correctly) and adding an option to my cmake command line, like Python_REQUIRED_COMPILER (so that it finds the g++ compiler correctly). I don't know how to use the Python_REQUIRED_COMPILER though.

Note : in C:\msys64\mingw64\bin there is g++.exe and also the python.exe. In C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 there is only python.exe.

What would be your suggestions ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Consider installing [Debian](https://debian.org/) on your laptop. Things would be easier

Comment: What do you mean by "Python fails to compile" ? Seems there are some system installations issues, since if regularly installed, all system executables (python.exe, g++, ...) would be in PATH. You should not have to tinker the PATH by yourself. I suggest you try to uninstall msys and Anaconda and cleanly reinstall all